# RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement a layout which contains `RecyclerView` and `ScrollView` at the same layout.

Layout template:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/myScrollView">

       <unrelated data>...</unrealated data>

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view" />
    </ScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problems: I can scroll until the last element of `ScrollView`.

Things I tried:

1. Card view inside the `ScrollView` (now `ScrollView` contains `RecyclerView`) - can see the card up until the `RecyclerView`.
2. Initial thought was to implement this `ViewGroup` using `RecyclerView` instead of `ScrollView` where one of it's views type is the `CardView`, but I got the exact same results as with the `ScrollView`.

Comment: checkout this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21878703/684582

Comment: a simple solution in many of these cases is to use `NestedScrollView` instead, as it handles a lot of scrolling issues

Comment: Richard gave you the answer in February. Use a `NestedScrollView` instead of a `ScrollView`. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing for me.

Comment: For future reference, if anybody is experiencing similar issue **only** marshmallow/nougat (API 23, 24) devices, check my workaround at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38995399/132121

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't recycle views in this layout hierarchy. You can verify by adding hundreds of items and checking the jank.

Comment: Try disabling the touch of recycler view when scrollview is being touched.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477270/3463571

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Also destroys the whole purpose of the RecyclerView. Views are not recycled so you end up having as many ViewHolder classes as items you have in the adapter.

Comment: @Farid with respect the OP presents a question with trade offs, and a request for specific nested scrolling behavior, if a `RecyclerView` inside some kind of scrolling layout. Accepted answer accomplishes the OP aims, because Google engineers realised there was a use case for this type of UI design. Obviously we hopefully all agree that if your use case is hitting jank due to non-recycling of views, then the UI design needs to be revisited and updated. However for most cases in the last 6 or 7 years, `NestedScrollView` > `ScrollView` for various reasons.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I get your point but "respecting" OP's use case will mislead thousand of newbies. Almost everyone has rushed to answer the question here rather than giving a little clue of the possible and dangerous pitfall. There are even oneliners without explanation and they got quite some upvotes that someone may think this is quite valid. Not blaming but giving a little insight is sometimes worth more than answer

Comment: I believe there are still good use cases for this technique today, as there were 6 years ago. It is great that the weaknesses have also been pointed so that any readers are able to form a balanced opinion of their own.

Answer (score 819, accepted):

use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Please go through [NestedScrollView reference document](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) for more information.

and add `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Works with : android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Comment: keep ``android:layout_height="wrap_content"`` for the layout inflated for ViewHolder

Comment: In a complex layout `NestedScrollView` lags for me, unlike the `ScrollView`. Searching for a solution without using `NestedScrollView`

Comment: It's working but my requirement is different, I have RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView and implementing paging for recyclerview and listening for the last position to fetch next data but it's not wokring, if I remove ScrollView or NestedScrollview then it's working fine. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: For below Lollipop versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43450158/7784230

Comment: In my case, I did took Horizontal RecyclerView within HorizontalScrollView and I also write this statement but It can't show me all the data which I stored in horizontal recyclerview

Comment: Also you can add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" to XML instead of recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: this worked for me but I have expandable items in recyclerview & the last item expands below visible screen . this wasn't the case with scrollView

Comment: It worked for me but keep in mind that the items inside recyclerView are not getting recycled.

Comment: it only for api level 21, how about level 19?

Comment: For those who stumble onto this answer and did everything right. hasFixedSize must be set to false on recyclerview for this to work.

Comment: @NandaZ, `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false)`.

Comment: @Thijs, `setHasFixedSize(true)` works right in my case.

Comment: The correct package to use is now `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: This doesn't work well at all.
Suppose you have 1000 items on the RecyclerView, it will create&bind them all right away...

Answer (score 120):

I know I am late it the game, but the issue still exists even after google has made fix on the `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

The issue I get now is `RecyclerView` with `layout_height=wrap_content` not taking height of all the items issue inside `ScrollView` that **only** happens on Marshmallow and Nougat+ (API 23, 24, 25) versions.
*(UPDATE: Replacing `ScrollView` with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` works on all versions. I somehow missed testing [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37338715/132121). Added this in my github project as demo.)*

After trying different things, I have found workaround that fixes this issue.

Here is my layout structure in a nutshell:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout> (vertical - this is the only child of scrollview)
     <SomeViews>
     <RecyclerView> (layout_height=wrap_content)
     <SomeOtherViews>
```

The workaround is the wrap the `RecyclerView` with `RelativeLayout`. Don't ask me how I found this workaround!!! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Complete example is available on **GitHub** project - https://github.com/amardeshbd/android-recycler-view-wrap-content

Here is a demo screencast showing the fix in action:

[image: Screencast]

Comment: Thanks man.. its help a lot.. but scrolling become hard after your solution so i set recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); and now its work like a charm.

Comment: Is this method recycle views? if we have around hundreds of object to be recycle. This is hack not solution.

Comment: Yes, @androidXP is right, this hack is not a solution for a long list. My use case was fixed item in a list view which was less than 10. And as for how I found the other workaround, I was trying random things, this was one of them :-)

Comment: perfect.solved my problem in adnroid marshmallow and upper. ;)

Comment: I think your solution is better but when I removed "setHasFixedSize(true);" it works more better

Comment: if I use this solution, then onBindView is getting called for all the items in the list, which is not the usecase of recyclerview.

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" helped me

Comment: Please don't ... check your memory usage. This hack is killing what "recycler" means.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, this is intended for a small list. I've also used it for long list with images without issue except memory consumption. So, yes, anybody planning to use this for long list is not a good idea.

Comment: This is not working if your data recyclerview source coming from api and you add "load more" feature. it will be load all data and would cause OutOfMemoryError

Comment: The use case I had was for limited fixed size items that look similar. As I mentioned earlier, don't use if the list size is dynamic and you expect to add more items dynamically.

Comment: I used stickyScrollview, and recyclerview was going above the StickyHeader, actually it should go below, after applying your solution, it worked like charm :) great man and thanks a ton.

Comment: @HossainKhan thank you. The fix without the nestedscroll worked for me, however its worth pointing out that ONLY RelativeLayout works, I tested Linear and Constraint and it wont work for some reason.

Comment: Btw, instead of `RelativeLayout` I have recently tried `FrameLayout` that also worked! :D

Answer (score 57):

Although the recommendation that

> you should never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view

Is a sound advice, however if you set a fixed height on the recycler view it should work fine.

If you know the height of the adapter item layout you could just calculate the height of the RecyclerView.

```
int viewHeight = adapterItemSize * adapterData.size();
recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = viewHeight;
```

Comment: How to get adapterItemSize in recyclerview any idea?

Comment: I set the height to be fixed but this disabled scrolling for me. How would i re-enable it. I simply did the above code amount of dp to px times size of items.

Comment: It works like a charm!
Little correction it should be : int viewHeight = adapterItemSize * adapterData.size(); recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = viewHeight;

Comment: How to find out adapterItemSize?

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom What is the `adapterItemSize` variable?

Comment: it will work.but it still consumes some event .not good for performance

Comment: when i put recyclerview inside scroll view, my adapter is never call....any suggestion?

Comment: For those having problems with touch events, either see if you override onInterceptTouch anywhere, and see what is done there. If you don't maybe it's a good idea too look at that api. Touch events are a tricky thing in android.

Comment: Avoid recycler view inside Scroll view, because scroll view give its child infinite space. This causes recycler view having wrap_content as height to measure infinitely in vertical direction(till the last item of recycler view). Instead of using recycler view inside scroll view, use only recycler view with different item types. With this implementation, children of scroll view would behave as as view type. Handle those viewtypes inside recycler view.

Comment: nested scroll view is made for such a purpose already. this recommendations is not recommended?

Comment: @MasoudDadashi Yes, you are right, this answer is not the best answer anymore.

Comment: using simple `wrap_content` as `layout_height` worked for me. No need of calculating the height.

Comment: Very bad solution, I mean we use recyclerview just to reuse the old views and if we assign the fixed height to recyclerview by your formula then recyclerview will not reuse that

Answer (score 35):

In case setting fixed height for the RecyclerView didn't work for someone (like me), here is what I've added to the fixed height solution:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Indeed, this worked well for me. With this in place, I was able to move the scroll view up and down, and when I select the recyclerview for scrolling, it takes priority over the scroll view. Thanks for the tip

Comment: it worked for me too, just be sure to use getParent on a direct child of the scrollview

Comment: This method works on cyanogenmod distributions as well. The fixed height solution on cyanogenmod works, but only if the fixed height is the absolute height of all of the items in the list, which defies the point of using the recyclerview in the first place. Upvoted.

Comment: I also needed recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: This really worked! It never occurred to me to set a touch listener at the item level. I tried (with no luck) to set a touch listener at the recyclerView level. Great solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 28):

The new **Android Support Library 23.2** solves that problem, you can now set *wrap_content* as the height of your `RecyclerView` and works correctly.

[Android Support Library 23.2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: doesn't fling properly too (23.4.0)

Comment: @behelit 23.4.0 have some issues https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210085#makechanges , use 23.2.1 instead

Comment: doesnt even fling properly on 25.0.1

Answer (score 18):

`RecyclerViews` are fine to put in `ScrollViews` so long as they aren't scrolling themselves.  In this case, it makes sense to make it a fixed height.

The proper solution is to use `wrap_content` on the `RecyclerView` height and then implement a custom `LinearLayoutManager` that can properly handle the wrapping.

Copy this LinearLayoutManager into your project: [link](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java)

Then wrap the `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And set it up like so:

```
RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setHasFixedSize(true);
list.setLayoutManager(new com.example.myapp.LinearLayoutManager(list.getContext()));
list.setAdapter(new MyViewAdapter(data));
```

Edit: This can cause complications with scrolling because the `RecyclerView` can steal the `ScrollView`'s touch events. My solution was just to ditch the `RecyclerView` in all and go with a `LinearLayout`, programmatically inflate subviews, and add them to the layout.

Comment: Couldn't you call setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) on the recyclerview?

Answer (score 17):

For `ScrollView`, you could use `fillViewport=true` and make `layout_height="match_parent"` as below and put `RecyclerView` inside:

```
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llOptions">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

No further height adjustment needed through code.

Comment: Tested working fine using v23.2.1 . Was using it for adding layout above recyclerview.

Comment: just the RecyclerView scrolling and the ScrollView not scrolling

Comment: Doesn't work , as it creates&binds to all items in the RecyclerView

Answer (score 15):

If you put `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` and enable `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`, scrolling will **working well**.
However, there is **a problem**

> `RecyclerView` **don't recycle**

For example, your `RecyclerView` (inside `NestedScrollView` or `ScrollView`) have 100 item.
When `Activity` launch, 100 item **will create** (`onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` of 100 item will called at same time).
Example, for each item, you will load a large image from API => activity created -> 100 image will load.
It make starting Activity slowness and lagging.
**Possible solution**:
 - Thinking about using `RecyclerView` with multiple type.

However, if in your case, there are just a few item in `RecyclerView` and **recycle** or **don't recycle** don't affect performance a lot, you can use `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` for simple

Comment: Show how can I make RecyclerView recycle even inside ScollView? Thanks!

Comment: @Liar, currently there is no way to make `RecyclerView` recycle after put it to `ScrollView`. If you want recycle, thinking about another approach (like using RecyclerView with multiple type)

Comment: you can give the recycler view a set height

Answer (score 14):

Calculating `RecyclerView`'s height manually is not good, better is to use a custom `LayoutManager`.

The reason for above issue is any view which has it's scroll (`ListView`, `GridView`, `RecyclerView`) failed to calculate it's height when add as a child in another view has scroll. So overriding its `onMeasure` method will solve the issue.

Please replace the default layout manager with the below:

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

    private static boolean canMakeInsetsDirty = true;
    private static Field insetsDirtyField = null;

    private static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 100;

    private final int[] childDimensions = new int[2];
    private final RecyclerView view;

    private int childSize = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE;
    private boolean hasChildSize;
    private int overScrollMode = ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS;
    private final Rect tmpRect = new Rect();

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.view = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.view = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public MyLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view) {
        super(view.getContext());
        this.view = view;
        this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public MyLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(view.getContext(), orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.view = view;
        this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
    }

    public void setOverScrollMode(int overScrollMode) {
        if (overScrollMode < ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS || overScrollMode > ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown overscroll mode: " + overScrollMode);
        }

        if (this.view == null) throw new IllegalStateException("view == null");

        this.overScrollMode = overScrollMode;
        ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, overScrollMode);
    }

    public static int makeUnspecifiedSpec() {
        return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);

        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

        final boolean hasWidthSize = widthMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
        final boolean hasHeightSize = heightMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

        final boolean exactWidth = widthMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        final boolean exactHeight = heightMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

        final int unspecified = makeUnspecifiedSpec();

        /** 
         * In case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's 
         * use default "onMeasure" implementation. 
         */
        if (exactWidth && exactHeight) {
            super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
            return;
        }

        final boolean vertical = getOrientation() == VERTICAL;

        initChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        /**
         * It's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) 
         * adapter entities. This happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" 
         * method. As a workaround let's clear the recycler now (it should not cause 
         * any performance issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never called whiles scrolling).
         */
        recycler.clear();

        final int stateItemCount = state.getItemCount();
        final int adapterItemCount = getItemCount();

        /**
         * Adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data
         * (f.e. data before the animation is done).  As we want to measure the view 
         * with actual data we must use data from the adapter and not from  the state.
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++) {
            if (vertical) {
                if (!hasChildSize) {
                    if (i < stateItemCount) {
                        /**
                         * We should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. 
                         * For such items we will use previously calculated dimensions.
                         */
                        measureChild(recycler, i, widthSize, unspecified, childDimensions);
                    } else {
                        logMeasureWarning(i);
                    }
                }
                height += childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
                }
                if (hasHeightSize && height >= heightSize) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (!hasChildSize) {
                    if (i < stateItemCount) {
                        /**
                         * We should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. 
                         * For such items we will use previously calculated dimensions.
                         */
                        measureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSize, childDimensions);
                    } else {
                        logMeasureWarning(i);
                    }
                }
                width += childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
                }
                if (hasWidthSize && width >= widthSize) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (exactWidth) {
            width = widthSize;
        } else {
            width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            if (hasWidthSize) {
                width = Math.min(width, widthSize);
            }
        }

        if (exactHeight) {
            height = heightSize;
        } else {
            height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
            if (hasHeightSize) {
                height = Math.min(height, heightSize);
            }
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (view != null && overScrollMode == ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS) {
            final boolean fit = (vertical && (!hasHeightSize || height < heightSize))
                || (!vertical && (!hasWidthSize || width < widthSize));

            ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, fit ? ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER : ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
        }
    }

    private void logMeasureWarning(int child) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("MyLinearLayoutManager", "Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                "To remove this message either use #setChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
        }
    }

    private void initChildDimensions(int width, int height, boolean vertical) {
        if (childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] != 0 || childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] != 0) {
            /** Already initialized, skipping. */
            return;
        }
        if (vertical) {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = width;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = childSize;
        } else {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = childSize;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = height;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        /** Might be called before the constructor of this class is called. */
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (childDimensions != null) {
            if (getOrientation() != orientation) {
                childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = 0;
                childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = 0;
            }
        }
        super.setOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public void clearChildSize() {
        hasChildSize = false;
        setChildSize(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE);
    }

    public void setChildSize(int childSize) {
        hasChildSize = true;
        if (this.childSize != childSize) {
            this.childSize = childSize;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    private void measureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSize, int heightSize, int[] dimensions) {
        final View child;
        try {
            child = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.w("MyLinearLayoutManager", "MyLinearLayoutManager doesn't work well with animations. Consider switching them off", e);
            }
            return;
        }

        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        final int hPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        final int vPadding = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        final int hMargin = p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        final int vMargin = p.topMargin + p.bottomMargin;

        /** We must make insets dirty in order calculateItemDecorationsForChild to work. */
        makeInsetsDirty(p);
        /** This method should be called before any getXxxDecorationXxx() methods. */
        calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, tmpRect);

        final int hDecoration = getRightDecorationWidth(child) + getLeftDecorationWidth(child);
        final int vDecoration = getTopDecorationHeight(child) + getBottomDecorationHeight(child);

        final int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthSize, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.width, canScrollHorizontally());
        final int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightSize, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.height, canScrollVertically());

        child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

        dimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        dimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;

        /** As view is recycled let's not keep old measured values. */
        makeInsetsDirty(p);
        recycler.recycleView(child);
    }

    private static void makeInsetsDirty(RecyclerView.LayoutParams p) {
        if (!canMakeInsetsDirty) return;

        try {
            if (insetsDirtyField == null) {
                insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
                insetsDirtyField.setAccessible(true);
            }
            insetsDirtyField.set(p, true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
        }
    }

    private static void onMakeInsertDirtyFailed() {
        canMakeInsetsDirty = false;
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("MyLinearLayoutManager", "Can't make LayoutParams insets dirty, decorations measurements might be incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i call this class when we set the data to adapter?

Answer (score 14):

Try this. Very late answer, but surely helps anyone in future.

1. Change your `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`:

   ```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
           ...
           ... />

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   ```
2. In your UI code, update it for `Recyclerview`:

   ```
   recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); 
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
   ```

Comment: using RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView is calling onBindView for every item in the list even if the item is not visible. Any solution for that problem?

Comment: You just need to give PaddingBottom into LinearLayout that is inside nestedScrollView - @thedarkpassenger

Answer (score 10):

***UPDATE:
this answer is out dated now as there are widgets like NestedScrollView and RecyclerView that support nested scrolling.***

you should never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view !

i suggest you make your main layout recycler view and put your views as items of recycler view.

take a look at this example it show how to use multiple views inside recycler view adapter.
[link to example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/2127203)

Comment: i have a page with more than one **Recycler**, is there any other way to persuade this? some thing like **instagram** or **google play** part comment that load more record when you click on _more comment_

Comment: make it a single recyclerView and put your views as items for that recycler

Comment: That is nonsense.  You can have nested RecyclerViews just fine.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. We have things like NestedScrollView that allow for nested scrollable views. Nested RecyclerViews also now work.

Answer (score 6):

Add this line to your `RecyclerView` xml view:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

And your `RecyclerView` will be smoothly scrolled with flexible height.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `NestedScrollView` does solve the problem.

I've tested using this layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dummy_text" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And it works without issues.

Comment: Bro, Still have the Same Problem After changed into NestedScrollview from the Scrollview.

Comment: mmm...can you share some code...I'm having zero issues but u can never know with this kind of issues

Comment: using this code calls onBindView for all the items in the list even if those items are not visible in the list. This defeats the purpose of recyclerview.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. That's what i tried and it works. I am sharing my xml and java code. Hope this will help someone.

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
< NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Buy" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reviews" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rc_reviews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView >
```

Here is the related java code. It works like a charm.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: What about layouts below RecyclerView?

Comment: that works as well. You just need to use. ```NestedScrollView``` instead of scroll view

Comment: Yes, only NestedScrollView. But solution with NestedScrollView+RecycleView call very slow populations of RecyclerView (I think for calcutaion of Y-position of first view after RecyclerView)

Comment: Doesn't work , as it creates&binds to all items in the RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

I used CustomLayoutManager to disable RecyclerView Scrolling.
Also don't use Recycler View as WrapContent, use it as 0dp, Weight=1

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean isScrollEnabled;

    // orientation should be LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL or HORIZONTAL
    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean isScrollEnabled) {
        super(context, orientation, false);
        this.isScrollEnabled = isScrollEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
```

Use CustomLayoutManager in RecyclerView:

```
CustomLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new CustomLayoutManager(getBaseActivity(), CustomLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        ((DefaultItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false); 
        recyclerView.setAdapter(statsAdapter);
```

UI XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main"
    android:fillViewport="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <edu.aku.family_hifazat.libraries.mpchart.charts.PieChart
                android:id="@+id/chart1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/x20dp"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/x300dp">

            </edu.aku.family_hifazat.libraries.mpchart.charts.PieChart>


        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the main purpose of the `RecyclerView` is to compensate for `ListView` and `ScrollView`. Instead of doing what you're actually doing: Having a `RecyclerView` in a `ScrollView`, I would suggest having only a `RecyclerView` that can handle many types of children.

Comment: This would work only provided that your children can be garbaged collected as soon as you scroll them out of view. If you have children that are mapFragments or streetviews, it doesn't make sense as they are forced to reload each time they scroll off the recyclerview. Embedded them into a scrollview and then generating a recyclerview at the bottom makes more sense then.

Comment: @Simon there's handy setIsRecyclable() in ViewHolder

Comment: RecyclerView replaces ListView it is not meant to replace ScrollView.

Comment: This comment deserves better. It is a solution, and even better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and put the `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`.

Use Custom layout class to measure the height and width of screen:

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    heightSpec,
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    widthSpec,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    recycler.bindViewToPosition(view, position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
}
```

And implement below code in the activity/fragment of `RecyclerView`:

```
 final CustomLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // Disables scrolling for RecyclerView, CustomLinearLayoutManager used instead of MyLinearLayoutManager
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            int lastVisibleItemPos = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.i("getChildCount", String.valueOf(visibleItemCount));
            Log.i("getItemCount", String.valueOf(totalItemCount));
            Log.i("lastVisibleItemPos", String.valueOf(lastVisibleItemPos));
            if ((visibleItemCount + lastVisibleItemPos) >= totalItemCount) {
                Log.i("LOG", "Last Item Reached!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It gets me an exception of `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid item position 0(0) ... CustomLinearLayoutManager.measureScrapChild(CustomLinearLayoutManager.java:68)` . That's even though the items count isn't 0.  Can you please post this sample on github?

Answer (score 0):

If RecyclerView showing only one row inside ScrollView. You just need to set height of your row to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also override `LinearLayoutManager` to make `RecyclerView` roll smoothly:

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically(){
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry being late to the party, but it seems like there is another solution which works perfectly for the case you mentioned.

If you use a recycler view inside a recycler view, it seems to work perfectly fine. I have personally tried and used it, and it seems to give no slowness and no jerkyness at all. Now I am not sure if this is a good practice or not, but nesting multiple recycler views , even nested scroll view slows down. But this seems to work nicely. Please give it a try. I am sure nesting is going to be perfectly fine with this.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to address the issue is to use `ConstraintLayout` inside `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView>
  <ConstraintLayout> (this is the only child of ScrollView)
    <...Some Views...>
    <RecyclerView> (layout_height=wrap_content)
    <...Some Other Views...>
```

But I would still stick to the `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` [approach, proposed by Yang Peiyong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37338715/231590).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with setting recycler view Hight as wrap_content.
in my case its working fine. I am trying with 2 different recycler view in scroll view

Answer (score 0):

****The best solution is to keep `multiple Views` in a `Single View / View Group` and then keep that one view in the SrcollView.**** ie.

*Format*  -

```
<ScrollView> 
  <Another View>
       <RecyclerView>
       <TextView>
       <And Other Views>
  </Another View>
</ScrollView>
```

Eg.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView           
              android:text="any text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <TextView           
              android:text="any text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </ScrollView>
```

Another Eg. of ScrollView with multiple Views

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/CategoryItem"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="₹1000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="so\nugh\nos\nghs\nrgh\n
                    sghs\noug\nhro\nghreo\nhgor\ngheroh\ngr\neoh\n
                    og\nhrf\ndhog\n
                    so\nugh\nos\nghs\nrgh\nsghs\noug\nhro\n
                    ghreo\nhgor\ngheroh\ngr\neoh\nog\nhrf\ndhog"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

             </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those people who trying to do it **just for design purposes** - leave it. Redesign your app and leave only `RecyclerView`. It will be better solution than doing **ANY** hardcode.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution which worked for me**

Use `NestedScrollView` with height as `wrap_content`, and for your `RecyclerView` setup this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

And set view holder layout params:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: [Some comments on a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337641/4515489) say disabling nested scrolling defeats the purpose of using a RecyclerView, i.e. that it won't recycle views.  Not sure how to confirm that.

Comment: Setting nestedScrollingEnabled="false" causes RecyclerView to NOT recycle its views, at least in my setup (a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView).  Confirmed by adding a RecyclerListener to the RecyclerView and setting a breakpoint inside its onViewRecycled() method.