# Many Horizontal RecyclerView in an Activity

Tags: android, xml

I have requirement where i need to have many horizontal `RecyclerView` It will have interface similar to Google PlayStore. Now the problem is If i add ScrollView in my layout and run app then it shows nothing on screen. 
When i remove it show `RecyclerView`

This is `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featured"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="#ECEFF1" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/latest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/startup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout
```

How should i solve this problem. I want to add `ScrollView` to activity which will have 9 to 10 horizontal `RecyclerView`

Comment: i think you should use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working

Comment: Thank for the suguestion and link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of the Recyclerviews to an actual dp value