# Does a RecyclerView with a fixed height still 'recycle' its elements?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I got into a situation where I have a ScrollView with some elements, where one of those elements is a table with many rows. I don't want my app to be laggy or use too much memory, so I thought it would help performance to use a RecyclerView for the table. But we all know the rule: Never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view. So I searched a bit, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working) question, where the accepted answer was to fix the size of the recyclerview.

Now my question is: Does this still improve performance? As far as I know, a RecyclerView recycles it's elements by reusing the elements that are not visible because the user scrolled down. But does it still do this if we forbid the RecyclerView to scroll and use it's parent (ore parents parent) to scroll?

Comment: If you don't allow the RecyclerView to scroll, why would it do anything? It's now in a fixed state...