# NestedScrollView not fling with Recyclerview inside

Tags: java, android

I have a layout like that:

```
<NestedScrollView>
     <RecyclerView> // vertical recycler view
          <RecyclerView/>  // horizontal recycler view
          <RecyclerView/>
          <RecyclerView/>
          ...
     <RecyclerView>
</NestedScrollView>
```

The result looks like Google play store:
[image]

And I disabled NestedScrolling in `horizontal Recycler` view:

```
horizontalRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
horizontalRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

## My problem:

The `vertical recyclerview` does not scroll fling, whenever `ACTION_UP` happen, the `vertical recyclerview` also stop scrolling.

How can I nest `vertical recyclerview` inside `nestedscrollview`, and `horizontal recyclerview` inside `vertical recyclerview` like Playstore and keep the scroll smooth.

## Solved:

Using custom nested scroll view of @vrund purohit (code below), and disabled nestedscroll both vertical and horizontal recyclerview:

```
verticalRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
... add each horizontal recyclerviews:
horizontalRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working/45466603#45466603 Check this link..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem and I solved this issue by customizing `NeatedScrollView`.

Here is the class for that.

**MyNestedScrollView**

```
public class MyNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int slop;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private float mInitialMotionX;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private float mInitialMotionY;
    public MyNestedScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context) {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
        slop = config.getScaledEdgeSlop();
    }
    public MyNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public MyNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }
    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();
            // This is very important line that fixes
            computeScroll();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
            lastX = curX;
            lastY = curY;
            if (xDistance > yDistance) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
        void onScrollChanged(NestedScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl,
                int oldt);
    }
    private OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;
    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mOnScrollChangedListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedListener != null) {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working/45466603#45466603

Comment: Is there any advantage over the simple answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43536382/905686)? If not, consider accepting the simpler one.

Answer (score 52):

Use below code for smooth scroll:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: put it in your `MainActivity.onCreate` or wherever you created your recyclerView

Comment: Perfect answer!

Also working in xml:

                            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

Thanks!

Comment: Best answer without a doubt!

Answer (score 11):

Add this in your RecyclerView xml:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Comment: This only works for API level 21 and above for below API level 21 see Kuldeeps answer.

Comment: If you're using databinding in your layout you can also create a bindingadapter:   @BindingAdapter("nestedScrollingEnabled")
    public static void setNestedScrollingEnabled(final View view, final boolean value) {
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(view, value);
    } and then add to layouts with                     app:nestedScrollingEnabled="@{false}"

Answer (score 4):

[RESOLVED] I have same issue with Horizontal recycleview. Change Gradle repo for recycleview

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
Write this: linearLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);

Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods in update

Check http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview

I have found issue with 23.2.1 library: When item is match_parent recycle view fill full item to view, please always go with min height or "wrap_content".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue by using below code:

```
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return true;
        }
    });
```