# Lazy-load views in RecyclerView within NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, androidx

Targeting `androidx` 1.0.0 to allow for pre-Lollipop devices (let's say `minSdkVersion 17` or so).

I have tried many combinations of views, settings, scrolling modes and layout managers. I have read everything - e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview/32736113) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384640/nestedscrollview-not-fling-with-recyclerview-inside) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655664/having-recyclerview-inside-a-nestedscrollview-calls-onbindview-for-all-the-items/50688421) - regarding this problem. Either I get bad layout/rendering performance or incorrect/buggy scrolling.

**Requirements:**

1. A bottomsheet is draggable from the bottom. A common UI pattern in modern apps.
2. 10-20 **heavy** equally sized child views. These must not be inflated/drawn when invisible.
3. Using native Android/Google views is *preferable*.

**How can I achieve this?**

Here's some pseudo code, showing what I'm trying to accomplish; a `RecyclerView` (or equivalent) inside a `NestedScrollView` with a `BottomSheetBehavior`:

```
<ScrollView>
  <!-- Main content -->
</ScrollView>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height">

    <!-- RecyclerView? -->  
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
            android:text="Bottom sheet header" />

        <-- N heavy equally sized child views here -->

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have read that `RecyclerView` outperforms `ListView`. Still, it seems to never recycle its views given the above configuration.

Comment: did you try a single RecyclerView with multiple view types?

Comment: No, I will try that. But even with that solution, it will keep inflating/drawing all views, right? My biggest concern is that the `RecyclerView` immediately draws all its children when shown. The scrolling seems to work quite well in `androidx:1.0.0`.

Comment: all the children are inflated and drawn as your RecyclerView is nested inside a NestedScrollView. A RecyclerView with multiple types is enough.

Comment: did u find any solution @l33t

Comment: I used a `ViewStub` in the end, inflating the views when expanding the bottom sheet the first time. Will improve on it in the future. So far all other attempts failed.