# RecyclerView inside a ScrollView/NestedScrollView does not scroll properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a layout which has a `CardView` and a `FloatingActionButton` associated with it. There is a list of replies below the `CardView` (which is a `RecyclerView`). Sometimes the `CardViews'` height is greater than the screen, so I have used `layout_height="wrap_content"` for the `CardView` and wrapped the whole `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.

However, this causes a problem(since it is a scrolling view inside a `ScrollView`) while scrolling the items of the `RecyclerView`. As suggested in some of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211286/2863440) posted, I have used both the `NestedScrollView` and the `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` tag but the scrolling in the `RecyclerView` is still bad.

Here is my `Layout` file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.forum.reply.ReplyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/reply_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/topic_card"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_margin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/card_margin"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/card_margin">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/topic_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/topic_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/reply_progressbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/list_of_replies"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/reply_to_topic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_reply_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/topic_card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are some images -

[image: CardView with FloatingActionButton visible]

[image: Scrolling from the CardView to RecyclerView is smooth]

[image: Scrolling down isn't smooth]

[image: Scrolling up also isn't smooth]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you have multiple scrolling Views in your layout (eg. RecyclerView + ScrollView) and when you scroll while in your recyclerView, the recyclerView scrolls with the parent Scrollview. this causes jitters in RecyclerView. You can avoid this jitter by the following.

You can add  
`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`
 to your RecyclerView in **XML** or 
 `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`
 to your RecyclerView in **Java**.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Also, I have to support devices older than API v21.

Comment: You have multiple scrolling Views in your layout, so when you scroll while touching your recyclerView, the recyclerView scrolls with the parent Scrollview. this causes jitters in RecyclerView, so with nestedScrollingEnabled="false" you kinda stop the scroll of recyclerView and the only scroll which is triggered is from the parent ScrollView. Also i do this programmatically with .setNestScrollingEnabled() and works fine for me on device older than API v21.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but could you update it with the things that you have mentioned in the comment.

Comment: because off above line my last card view is cutting off

Comment: Note that if you want to support devices older than v21 you have to use `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false);` @yadav_vi

Answer (score 10):

If you want to support devices older than api 21 then you should use

`ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false);`

in your Activity/Fragment

Comment: Can you please explain why my answer is wrong and I got down voted? I would like to know if I am mistaken, because I use the above snippet in my code and it works just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to do multiple tasks:

1. put your recyclerview inside a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of normal `ScrollView`
2. set your recyclerview `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in layout XML file
3. to support devices older than API 21 then you should use `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false)` in your code
4. set your RecyclerView height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` (or width if it is horizontal!)

Answer (score 3):

Besides Setting the `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` you need to make sure that the parent of the RecyclerView is a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

I had troubles that the RecyclerView did not measure properly (on big screens) when it was in a standard `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to scroll RecyclerView inside ScrollView and ScrollView prevents from scrolling RecyclerView (in API 16 this occurred) you should use android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
instead of ScrollView and also you must set
       nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
by this way you can prevent from scrolling nestedScrollView when you scroll RecyclerView.
hope this help some one

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem ,solving it with :
custom ScrollView and override onInterceptTouchEvent to return false.

hope it's help someone/