# RecyclerView Laggy inside NestedScrollView/LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Before digging into the code, I've already checked the following questions:

1. [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)
2. [Recyclerview inside Nested Scrollview scroll but does not fast scroll like normal Recyclerview or Nested Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301724/recyclerview-inside-nested-scrollview-scroll-but-does-not-fast-scroll-like-norma)
3. [RecyclerView inside a ScrollView/NestedScrollView does not scroll properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909312/recyclerview-inside-a-scrollview-nestedscrollview-does-not-scroll-properly)

None of the aforementioned questions has worked with me. The `RecyclerView` is too laggy when scrolling.

I have a `NestedScrollview` and a `LinearLayout` as a main Layout for the `NestedScrollview`. Layout's code is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/frag_misc_rv_margin_top"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/frag_showcase_promotion_recyclerview"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The code is:

```
mPromotionsRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
mPromotionsRv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
mPromotionsAdapter = new ShowcasePromotionRvAdapter(getActivity(), mPromotionsItems);
mPromotionsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ShowcasePromotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            ItemPromotion mPromotion = mPromotionsItems.get(position);
            try{
                recordPromotionClick(mPromotion.getId());
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(mPromotion.getPromotion_link())));
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    mPromotionsRv.setAdapter(mPromotionsAdapter);
    SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
    snapHelperStart.attachToRecyclerView(mPromotionsRv);


    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = mPromotionsRv.getItemAnimator();
    if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) { ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false); }
```

Comment: Essentially no matter what, using `wrap_content` with `RecyclerView` is always going to risk using too many resources.

Comment: I've tried setting the height and didn't really help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since your RecyclerView is Horizontal, try making your RecyclerView's width "wrap_content".