# Navigation bar with scroll view android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, navigation-drawer

This is my layout which is using the nav bar and scroll view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".AccountActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- your content layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:elevation="0dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--content of account activity-->

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            >

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/activity_setup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".AccountActivity">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/listgrad"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profilepic"
                    android:id="@+id/accountnamefield"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Recently Match"
                    android:id="@+id/recentMatchTitle"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/accountnamefield"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recentMatchProductList"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/recentMatchTitle"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_account_circle_white_36dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profilepic"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am using scroll view with the nav drawer. Why do I open and close the nav drawer then the view will scroll to bottom position? Can I move it to top or remain the same position? Please give me some helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:inputType="textPersonName"` part first for `TextView`.Then 
add `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to your `ScrollView` .It worked fine for me.

Here I will post the code I used for testing, `ScrollView` kept same position while using `NavigationDrawer`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- your content layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:elevation="0dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--content of account activity-->

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/activity_setup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/bla"
                    android:id="@+id/accountnamefield"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Recently Match"
                    android:id="@+id/recentMatchTitle"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/accountnamefield"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I cannot solve my problem. I think scroll view is affected by the recycler view so it go to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout has bunch of problems:

android:layout_alignParentStart="true" - the same thing as left (or right for RTL)
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" - the same thing as right (or
    left for RTL)

It's wrong to declare start and left in the same time

Using a recycler view inside ScrollView - bad practice and will never work. You can use nested scroll view ([RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working)), but the better solution is put what you want inside scroll view (as headers and footers).

I think there is no way to measure your layout.  Try to figure out how android is drawing views (https://medium.com/@britt.barak/measure-layout-draw-483c6a4d2fab#.y7nd8gyql).

P.S. You have much more problems with your layout, it's easier to write a new one, than pointing all problems.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentStart="true" and android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" was generated automatically when I use xml to drag the view. I would have a look for that website and I am still not very good to handle so many views in one activity. Thank you.