# Add item to RecyclerView from AlertDialog input

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm currently having trouble with adding a second+ items to a `RecyclerView` after inputting data in an alertdialog box.

I can enter 1 set of data but when I try to add more, it doesn't do anything.

This is my Java file for the fragment i'm working with:

```
public class tab1Expenses extends Fragment  {
    List<ExRow> expenseList = new ArrayList();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ExpensesAdapter mAdapter;
    Button btnEx;
    EditText txtExName;
    EditText txtExAmount;

    public void expenseData() {
        String Na = txtExName.getText().toString();
        String Am = txtExAmount.getText().toString();

        ExRow exs = new ExRow(Na, Am);
        expenseList.add(exs);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1expense, container, false);
        btnEx = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEx);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new ExpensesAdapter(expenseList);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 
        btnEx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity())
                    .inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
                txtExName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exName);
                txtExAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);

                AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity());
                add.setCancelable(true)
                    .setTitle("Enter Expense:")
                    .setView(view)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            expenseData();
                        }
                   });
                Dialog dialog = add.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the Java file for the adapter:

```
public class ExpensesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpensesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<ExRow> expenseList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, amount;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        }
    }

    public ExpensesAdapter(List<ExRow> expenseList) {
        this.expenseList = expenseList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.expense_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExRow expense = expenseList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(expense.getTitle());
        holder.amount.setText(expense.getAmount());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return expenseList.size();
    }
}
```

The XML to format the recyclerview list items:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the XML for the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ojemz.expensetracker.tab1Expenses"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<Button
    android:text="Add Expense"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnEx"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


          <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" />
            
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: This is how im inputting information]
[image: This is what I currently see AFTER adding a 2nd input]

This is what I currently see AFTER adding a 2nd input

Comment: It's strange. Maybe, I didn't notice something but this code must work. Is it a full adapter code?

Comment: I believe it is

Comment: Please, check that it doesn't add just empty items to the `RecyclerView` (without text).

Comment: You can set a break point and check that it executes all correct. It will help to find a bug. Also post all XMLs, maybe, just some view has 0 width or height.

Comment: I updated the question with the XML's. I'm currently working on making sure the items aren't empty from the input

Comment: It's not bug but `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was to do with the height of the relative layout for the recycler items. It was on match parent, i switched to wrap content and it now displays the inputs on the screen

Comment: So, it just added an empty items (it's more true, invisible items) =)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

Your `RecyclerView` has 0 height now. You need to add a some fixed height to it and set a scroll behaviour. Or you can use `NestedScrollView` or write `LayoutManager` with the full height expansion.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working) for details.

**ADDED**
Use this XML instead of your but I wrote it without IDE so it can contain some errors.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ojemz.expensetracker.tab1Expenses"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:keepScreenOn="true" />

        <Button
            android:text="Add Expense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnEx"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I did that. I set the height to 800dp and match parent and used NestedScrollView and still can only get 1 item. any items after that do not appear

Comment: Post a new variant, please. And you use wrong xml tags for inner views, these tags do nothing in this context.

Comment: And what's for you use this `ScrollView`. Do you have there yet views? Post them too.

Comment: I updated with pictures. The scrollview may not be necessary.

Comment: This is my first time taking on a project this big, so sorry for rookie mistakes lol

Comment: I used your XML and it didn't solve the issue. I still only can get 1 input before the new inputs dont appear. It does simply my XML code so I will keep it.

Comment: Yeah, this variant is more optimised

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why this wont work. I've seen people use .notifyDataSetChanged(position + 1); but it doesnt allow me to do that. passing an int position makes everything get all messy.

Comment: Guy, give me a link for source. It will be more fast)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134284/discussion-between-corpse-and-).