# Android I want to make recyclerView have same fast scroll in Netflix app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have 7 horizontal recyclerview in fragment in nested scroller the problem when I scroll the hole page or the recycler view the interface stop 1 second
I see NetFlix the film and program recycler is very fast but in my app the recycler not take from first touch 
Note: my app is very similar to NetFlix

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/kufi_bold_0"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/category"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/categoryRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
                    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
                    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
                    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi. Please post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

In the xml layout file you can set

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

by the RecyclerView attribute

Hop this helps