# Recyclerview Elements get cut off at the end of the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show a list of people using Recyclerview. But the List just gets cut off at the end of the screen.
If i change the layout more people are shown but it still gets cut off at the end of the screen

The first list should have 12 Elements whereas it only shows the 9 / 10 elements which are initially visible even though the rest of the elements should be visible if I scroll down.
If the recyclerview is initially completely invisible(see the second one) then all elements can be seen on scrolling.

Images:

https://ibb.co/kg2q03H

https://ibb.co/19YgXT9

https://ibb.co/0f03GKH

https://ibb.co/3vpgQSp

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ViewDetails" android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
>
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/table">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/wappentransparent"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="Musikprobe"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nameText"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" android:id="@+id/date" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_date_range"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="01.01.2000"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dateText"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" android:id="@+id/time" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_schedule_black_24dp"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="12:00"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/timeText"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="Uhr"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/uhrConst"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:id="@+id/infoTabRow">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" android:id="@+id/info" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_event_note"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="Hier steht ganz viel info und so"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/infoText"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <View
                        android:id="@+id/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/signOut"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                            android:text="ABMELDEN"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/signUp"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/signUp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                            android:text="ANMELDEN"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <View
                        android:id="@+id/divider2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/signedInHeader">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" android:id="@+id/signedUp" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_people_green"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/teilnehmer"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:text="Teilnehmer" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvTeilnehmer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="56dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/signedOutHeader">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" android:id="@+id/signedOut" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_people_red"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/abgesagt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:text="Abgesagt" android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvAbgesagt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"/>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```
        rvsi = view.findViewById(R.id.rvTeilnehmer)
        val llmsi = object : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
            override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }
        rvsi!!.layoutManager = llmsi
        rvsi!!.adapter = RVPersonAdapter(PersonList().persons)
//PersonList().person is an arraylist of 12 Persons(which contain a String with the name)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what your issue is - do you mean that when you try to scroll your RecyclerView, there are no more elements aside from the ones that are visible initially?

Also, you mention scrolling to a second RecyclerView, are these RecyclerViews contained within a parent view that can scroll? Consider including the full layout context, and possibly show some of the view binding logic as that could also be a culprit.

Comment: the adapter for the recyclerview contains 12 elements when i add it to the recyclerview. <https://ibb.co/kg2q03H> <- Thats what you see when you open the fragment. But if you scroll down you don't see the rest of the elements, instead the next tablerow from the layout is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated post, it seems you may be having an issue with nested scrolling. See [RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working).

The gist of it is that you will need to replace your ScrollView with a NestedScrollView and then set a flag in your RecyclerViews to allow it to scroll properly.

If you don't use the NestedScrollView, the parent ScrollView will intercept all of the scroll events instead of sending them to the RecyclerViews - so the items are technically there in the recyclers, you just can't get to them.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using **multi-view type RecyclerView** rather than RecyclerView in ScrollView. You can use NestedScrollView+RecyclerView as *@VerumCH* suggested above (also you should disable nested scrolling by setting nestedScrollingEnabled attribute of RecyclerView as false), but there is another problem. If you will use RecyclerView in NestedScrollView, list views will not be recycled & will be given you at once.

Comment: Also, as I have noticed you use kotlin, if you are interested in multi-view type recyclerView, there are many alternatives with sealed classes, interfaces and so on