# RecyclerView not scrolling inside NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm designing a complex UI that has a NestedScrollView as a parent and inside it, there is a RecyclerView. Now the problem is that I'm not able to scroll the items inside the RecyclerView.

Things I've tried

- Replacing ScrollView with NestedScrollView
- Enabling android:fillViewport="true"
- Disabling NestedScrolling of RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.StudentPreview">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarCV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:translationY="-45dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#1641A2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menuIV"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/featureName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
                android:text="Student Preview"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/studentPreviewNSV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/avatarCV"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"

                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/studentDetailsCL"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/studentDetailsCL"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/studentDetailsCL">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatarIV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:src="@drawable/avatar_sample" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameInitialTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:text="AK"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/studentDetailsCL"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatarCV"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/studentNameTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Akrit Khanna" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/classNameTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/studentNameTV"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/studentNameTV"
                    tools:text="Class 8th A" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lastLoggedTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/classNameTV"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/classNameTV"
                    tools:text="Last Logged: 30-01-2020" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/classEnrollCV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#F5F5F5"
                app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
                app:cardElevation="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/courseEnrollCV"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/detailsGL">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/classEnrollCountTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/classEnrollTVContainerFL"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:text="1" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/classEnrollTVContainerFL"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:background="#D0D9EC"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:text="Classes Enrolled"
                            android:textColor="#1641A2"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />


                    </FrameLayout>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/courseEnrollCV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#F5F5F5"
                app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
                app:cardElevation="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/classEnrollCV"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/detailsGL">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/courseEnrollCountTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/courseEnrollTVContainerFL"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:text="1" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/courseEnrollTVContainerFL"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:background="#D0D9EC"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:text="Courses Enrolled"
                            android:textColor="#1641A2"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />


                    </FrameLayout>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/detailsGL"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="90dp" />


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/reportCL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#F5F5F5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/classEnrollCV">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/classOrTermSpinner"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/courseSpinner"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/courseSpinner"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/classOrTermSpinner"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/reportRV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/courseSpinner" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can try to move your RecylerView ConstraintLayout which is one level higher

Comment: Still the same problem @AlexRmcf

Comment: Sorry, was wrong. I mean that your recycler view suppose to be outside of nested scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by adding **android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"**
I think this was happening because I gave android:layout_marginTop="90dp" to my NestedScrollView and due to that RecyclerView was assuming that all the items are visible on the screen so there is no need for scrolling. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

```
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/reportRV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/courseSpinner"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/report_list_layout"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NestedScrolView` and add this to your RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

Or this to the XML:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Also it might help to add orientation to the recyclerView:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: I have already done this programmatically. But it is still not working.

Comment: may be irrelevant but add orientation to the recyclerView and test.

Comment: also try this: recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

Comment: and if none of that works. maybe this will: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995399/10695663

Comment: Tried setting recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false); but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the views present inside `NestedScrollView` into a `RelativeLayout`. For ex,

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/studentPreviewNSV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- your remaining code -->

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Still the same problem.