# Recyclerview not call any Adapter method :onCreateViewHolder,onBindViewHolder,

Tags: java, android, listadapter, android-recyclerview

my RecyclerView do not call onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder, therefore, does not appear nothing in recyclerview. I put logs for debugging, and no log is shown. What can be?

My adapter:

```
public class CommentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
private static final int EMPTY_VIEW = 10 ;
private ArrayList<comment> mItems;
Boolean firstTime = true;
private Typeface mTf = null;
Context mContext;
public CommentListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<comment> items){
    Log.e("Adapter", "constructor Called");
    this.mItems = items;
    mContext = context;
}
public class EmptyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public EmptyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView mAuthorName;
    TextView mMessage;
    NetworkImageView mThumbnail;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mAuthorName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_name);
        mMessage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        mThumbnail = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_avatar);
    }

}

public void add(comment item, int position) {
    mItems.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(comment item) {
    int position = mItems.indexOf(item);
    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    Log.e("Adapter", "onCreateViewHolder Called");
    View v;
    if(firstTime){
        mTf = BBcTypeFace.getTypeFace(parent.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"font/bbc.ttf");
        firstTime = false;
    }
    if( viewType == EMPTY_VIEW){
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.comment_empty_row,parent,false);
        EmptyViewHolder evh = new EmptyViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.comment_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Log.e("Adapter", "onBindViewHolder Called");
    if(viewHolder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
        comment c = mItems.get(position);
        Log.e("Adapter", "Comment is\n: " + c.toString());
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(c.author_img_link, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    finalHolder.mThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 0, null,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        VolleyLog.e("ImageLoader", volleyError.getMessage());
                        VolleyLog.e("ImageLoader", volleyError.getStackTrace());
                    }
                });
        GetVideoInfo.getInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
        holder.mAuthorName.setText(c.author_name);
        holder.mMessage.setText(c.Message);
        holder.mMessage.setTypeface(mTf);
        holder.mAuthorName.setTypeface(mTf);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Adapter", "getItemCount() Called");
    return (mItems.size() > 0 ? mItems.size() : 1);
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Log.e("Adapter", "getItemViewType() Called");
    if (mItems.size() == 0) {
        return EMPTY_VIEW;
    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}}
```

I will use `public void add(comment item, int position){...}` to add item in RecyclerView.

in Fragment :

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CommentListAdapter mAdapter;
private LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
....

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mAdapter = new CommentListAdapter(getActivity(),new ArrayList<comment>());
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    makeJsonObjectRequest(mItem.url);
    return rootView;
}
```

XML Files :

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    ....
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
.....

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/comment_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
....
        </RelativeLayout>
    ....
</ScrollView>
```

comment_row xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/author_name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/author_avatar"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/author_avatar"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_below="@+id/author_name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/author_avatar"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/author_avatar"
            android:gravity="right" />
        </LinearLayout>

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/author_avatar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:minWidth="150dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

I will add item to RecyclerView with this code :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReqComment = new
             JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,urlJsonObj+"#comment", null,
                     new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                             try {
                                 JSONArray res = response.getJSONArray("response");
                                 //Log.e("Comment","Count:"+response.toString());
                                 //Log.e("Comment","Count:"+res.length());
                                 for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) {
                                     JSONObject thread = res.getJSONObject(i);
                                     JSONObject author_json = thread.getJSONObject("author");
                                     int dislikes = thread.getInt("dislikes");
                                     int likes = thread.getInt("likes");
                                     String Message = thread.getString("message");
                                     //get Author info
                                     String author_img_link = author_json.getJSONObject("avatar").getString("permalink");
                                     String author_name = author_json.getString("name");
                                     comment c = new comment(dislikes,likes,Message,author_img_link,author_name);
                                     //Log.e("Comment",c.toString());
                                     //commentsList.add(c);
                                     mAdapter.add(c,0);
                                 }

                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 Log.e("OnResponse","Error JSON");
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             } catch (Exception e){
                                 Log.e("OnResponse","Error Exception");
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }


                         }
                     }
                     , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     VolleyLog.d("vOLLEY", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                     // hide the progress dialog

                 }
             }
             ){
                 @Override
                 public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                     Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     headers.put("User-agent", "Comment");
                     return headers;
                 }
             };
```

Comment: A row matching parent on both width and height? Are you sure you want that?

Comment: You are not even getting getItemCount ? That is quite weird.

Besides that, your empty view implementation is wrong. When you add an item for the first time, you should first call notifyItemRemoved(0) so that RV  knows item 0 is removed.  Also, your getItemViewType implementation is quite risky as RV may call it while EMPTY view is a part of the UI but new items are just added so this is quite risky. I would suggest to have a boolean in your adapter that sets shouldEmpty view and when it is set to false, you should call notifyItemRemoved(0). Make sure it happens before adding items .

Comment: @PedroOliveira I changed to android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" , dosen't change any thing

Comment: @yigit RecyclerView just call getItemCount(), but RecyclerView don't call other Override methods,
I try this code without EmptyViewHolder with Initial data, but I have this problem too,
excuse me, if my english is poor

Comment: So not even a call to onCreate or onBind for EMPTY View? also, did you debug if `add` is being called?

Comment: I think when getItemCount() returns 0, it wont call other methods. Can you show us the part where you're actually adding items to the adapter ?

Comment: @yigit yes I call add method too, and I see this problem

Comment: @ShivamVerma getItemCount() return >= 1, I will update my question.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I add some code at end of my question.

Comment: I think, the problem is with this line : `mAdapter.add(c,0);` You're always adding the item at the 0th position which tells android that the item at position at 0 has changed and it tries to just redraw the 0th item position. 

Can you try adding something like `mAdapter.add(c,i);`

Comment: @ShivamVerma, nope, calling add(c, 0) only means it will add the new item to position 0 and push other items down (so empty view moves to position 1).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, just read the documentation.

Comment: @SanatiSharif, if you can upload a sample project, i'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: @yigit Is there a possibility of Wrong Thread Exception ? Given that   `mAdapter.add(c,0);` is possibly being called from a background thread and the `notifyItemInserted()` method needs to run on the UI thread ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma nope,  Volley onResponse run on main (UI) Thread

Comment: @yigit its huge project, I can't upload it,

Comment: Ok, one last thing. Check the height of your RV. Try setting a fixed height. Maybe the combination of ScrollView, RL and RV causes it to have 0 height (which would explain not getting any views because there is no room). I don't understand why you have that setup anyways. 
Besides that, I cannot see what else is going wrong. If there was a bug in RV like this, it would be pretty obvious and surface itself way before.

Comment: @yigit excuse me I'm new in android programing, what is RL and RV ?
Thanks,

Comment: RL = relative layout
RV = recyclerview

Comment: Always specify layout manager. I keep forgetting about that!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As @yigit guess  the combination of `ScrollView`, `RelativeLayout` causes this problem,
Just make more room for `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks.  Preview the xml to ensure that the recycle view is displayed.

Comment: Mine is not inside a ScrollView, yet still having this problem.

Comment: I had my RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout so it was not calling any adapter methods. Crazy :x

Answer (score 193):

Other than @SanatiSharif's and @sohrab's answer, you have to follow below mandatory step.

Make sure you call `setLayoutManager`, something like below.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

before setting adapter into recyclerView, otherwise it is not going to work.
You can customize it if you need. 
[this link](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/10-steps-to-create-a-custom-layoutmanager-2f30ab2f979d#.a8igwto8g) will give you some idea of how LayoutManager works.

Comment: the question is, why is this needed? This answer solves my problem but I don't know why.

Comment: You can also set this via XML:
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

Answer (score 19):

> If RecyclerView gets put into a ScrollView, then during measure step its height is unspecified (because ScrollView allows any height) and gets equal to minimum height (as per implementation) which is apparently zero.

ref : [android: RecyclerView inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515904/android-recyclerview-inside-a-scrollview)

Solution : 
- put views in row of RecyclerViews
- Calculate the size of the list items and set the height of the ListView programmatically
http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2014/04/android-listview-inside-scrollview.html

Answer (score 7):

Might have been a different case but for me I just forgot to set the Layout Manager as follows:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6):

Its late but hope it will help somone. try either of the following:

first solution:
make sure you haven't use this line unnecessarily

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

second solution:
make sure you set layout manager to `recyclerView`

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

third solution:
you `getItemCount` returns 0, So `RecyclerView` never tries to instantiate a view. Make it return something greater than 0

Answer (score 3):

In my Case I was using Fragment-> ViewPager and Tablayout -> Inside viewpagers item I used RecyclerView.

So Instead of calling  **ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())**  , I was calling  ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())  , that is why any of my recycler adapter item is not getting called.

So proper way to set the ViewPagerAdapter within a fragment is

> ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())

Answer (score 1):

In my case i  had this  structure

```
<ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i solved the problem remove Relative

```
<ScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is kind of silly, but another thing that can block the calls to the methods is to declare the visibility of the view as GONE.

```
android:visibility="gone"

recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Any of these will block the call of the methods in RecyclerView.Adapter

I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but none of the above answers helped me.

Finally, I found out I made a mistake when creating and binding the view for the Fragment in which my RecyclerView was living:

### Problematic Code

**FormPageFragment.onCreate**

```
binding=FormPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

but in onCreateView I did this:

**FormPageFragment.onCreateView**

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_page, container, false)
```

and later in onStart setting the adapter like this:

**FormPageFragment.onStart**

```
binding.formContent.adapter=FormEntriesAdapter(page, viewModel.enteredData)
```

### Solution

But this was rubbish. It should have all be done in onCreateView and of course the **binding.rootView needs to be returned as view**, other wise the bindings views are not attached to the layout and setting any adapters on them has no effect.

***working version of onCreateView***

```
 binding=FormPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 return binding.root
```

So it was more a problem with fragment instanciation, creating and binding the correct views than with the RecyclerView itself.