# E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

By the title of this question, its easily understandable that, the adapter of recyclerview is not set inside a UI thread. But in my case to avoid that I have tried doing it even on UI thread but still no luck.

I am using FirebaseUI for my app. Below is the code snippet:

```
public static void getUserFromUserId(@NonNull DatabaseReference dbRef, @NonNull String userId) {
    dbRef.child(USERS).child(userId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    FriendsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Handler() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            loadFriends(user);
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    FirebaseCrash.report(databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
}

private void loadFriends(User user) {
    Query friendsRef = ;  // your firebase DatabseReference path
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friend, FriendViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friend, FriendViewHolder>(Friend.class,
                    R.layout.item_challenge, FriendViewHolder.class, friendsRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(FriendViewHolder viewHolder, Friend model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setFriendName(model.getName());
                    viewHolder.setFriendPic(FriendActivity.this, model.getProfilePic());
                }
            };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My Activity's onCreate() method has below code related to RecyclerView:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.challenge_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

I dont understand why even after calling `loadFriends` inside `runOnUiThread`, why the error still persists.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is recyclerview displaying the items?

Comment: Not displaying. Thats what my question is.

Comment: Just set an empty adapter first, update it as soon as you have the data..!! And **Make sure your `getItemCount()` is not returning `0`**..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach your adapter when you initialize your `RecyclerView` and attach LayoutManager, etc.

`loadFriends` method should fetch data and add data to the adapter and then you should call `notifyDataSetChanged` or equivalent.

What you're doing here is incorrect. A recyclerview should always have an adapter attached. You just need to update the data in the adapter.

And that's what the error says `E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout`. Because you have not attached adapter after attaching LayoutManager and you're attaching adapter at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding LayoutManager in your recyclerView?

Make sure you call `setLayoutManager`, like below.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

before setting adapter into recyclerView, otherwise it is not gonna work.

Source : - [recyclerview-not-call-any-adapter-method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36488971/519718)

Comment: Code inside my onCreate() method:mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.challenge_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);