# RecyclerView No adapter attached; skipping layout, Data not showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm making a music player application where I'm using a loader to load song data to the adapter which is to be shown using a RecyclerView. However, I'm getting this weird error of my adapter methods not working. Only the constructor method of adapter is getting called.
I'm also getting "No adapter attached; skipping layout" despite going through all the available solutions here in stack overflow.

**Few points to be noted:**

- I've tried all the solutions for "No adapter attached; skipping layout" in 
  [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout) thread and all associated duplicate threads.
- The RecyclerView I'm using is not the regular one but [FastScrollRecyclerView](https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll), but since it extends from the regular RecyclerView and there are no relatable issues mentioned on github so I'm convinced that using this library is not an issue here
- I've also tried all solutions for the adapter methods not being called from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115553/recyclerview-not-call-any-adapter-method-oncreateviewholder-onbindviewholder) thread but no luck.

**Here's the code:**

SongsFragment.java

```
public class SongsFragment extends Fragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Song>>{

public static final String LOG_TAG = SongsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private SongListAdapter mSongListAdapter;
private List<Song> mSongs;
@BindView(R.id.rvSongs) FastScrollRecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public SongsFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());
    mSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView = new FastScrollRecyclerView(getContext());
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mSongListAdapter = new SongListAdapter(getContext(), mSongs);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSongListAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this).forceLoad();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Song>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    mContentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    return new SongsLoader(getContext(), mContentResolver);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Song>> loader, List<Song> data) {
    mSongs = data;
    mSongListAdapter.setData(mSongs);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Song>> loader) {
    mSongListAdapter.setData(new ArrayList<Song>());
}
```

}

SongsListAdapter.java

```
public class SongListAdapter
  extends FastScrollRecyclerView.Adapter<SongListAdapter.SongItemViewHolder>
  implements FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter{

public static final String LOG_TAG = SongListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;
private List<Song> mSongList = new ArrayList<>();

public SongListAdapter(Context context, List<Song> songList) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Constructor called");
    mContext = context;
    mSongList = songList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public String getSectionName(int position) {
    return String.valueOf(mSongList.get(position).getTitle().charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
}

@Override
public SongItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateViewHolder called");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_song, null);
    return new SongItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SongItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBindViewHolder called");
    Uri albumArtUri = mSongList.get(position).getAlbumArtUri();
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .into(holder.albumArt);
    holder.titleText.setText(mSongList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.artistText.setText(mSongList.get(position).getArtistName());
    Log.d("Data", albumArtUri.toString() + "\n" + mSongList.get(position).getTitle() + "\n" + mSongList.get(position).getArtistName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getItemCount called");
    return (mSongList != null ? mSongList.size() : 0);
}

public void setData(List<Song> songs){
    mSongList = songs;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class SongItemViewHolder extends FastScrollRecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView albumArt;
    TextView titleText;
    TextView artistText;

    SongItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SongItemViewHolder called");
        albumArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_song_image);
        titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_song_title);
        artistText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_song_artist_name);
    }
}
```

}

fragment_songs.xml (SongsFragment is inflating this layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.simplecityapps.recyclerview_fastscroll.views.FastScrollRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fastScrollPopupBgColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fastScrollPopupTextColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        app:fastScrollThumbColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

</ScrollView>
```

list_item_song.xml (Individual item in recycler view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_song_image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/music_placeholder"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_song_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Song_Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_song_artist_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Song_Artist"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This has been really frustrating. Please review the code and help me with this. I think I've done everything correctly but I may be wrong. I know scrollview and recyclerview don't go that well but I've seen the preview and the recycler view shows. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Log the size of the list being supplied to your `SongListAdapter.setData()`.

Comment: Used a log statement to know the size of the list passing on to `SongListAdapter.setData()` . The size is 609. 609 songs are passed to that song for my device.

Comment: Do you get `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getItemCount called");`?

Comment: No, only the log in SongsListAdapter constructor appears

Comment: Try wrapping your `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `runOnUIThread()` juat for the sake of it.

Comment: Just tried it but not working. It's taking forever to debug this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh! I wasted a lot of time in this but finally came out with the solution. I removed Butterknife binding and used conventional `findViewById` inside `onCreateView()` of `SongsFragment` after capturing the view instance by changing the `onCreateView()` to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
mRecyclerView = (FastScrollRecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvSongs);
//Rest of the things
}
```

Turns out I was using ButterKnife the wrong way so the instance `mRecyclerView` was null but later with line 
`mRecyclerView = new FastScrollRecyclerView(getContext());` it wasn't null anymore but it still wasn't connected to the view so I didn't get `NullPointerException` and the code didn't work.

I know it was a noob mistake :D

Correct way to use ButterKnife with fragments as picked up from official website is:

```
public class FancyFragment extends Fragment {
  @BindView(R.id.button1) Button button1;
  @BindView(R.id.button2) Button button2;

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting adapter in  `onLoadFinished()` and also use `getActivity()` for context in adapter object

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Song>> loader, List<Song> data) {
    mSongs = data;
     mSongListAdapter = new SongListAdapter(getActivity(), mSongs);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSongListAdapter);
}
```

also in this 
`mRecyclerView = new FastScrollRecyclerView(getContext());` to

```
mRecyclerView = new FastScrollRecyclerView(getActivity());
```

Basically use `getActivity()` for context in fragment class

Comment: Have already tried to set adapter in onLoadFinished() but that didn't work out. Tried using getActivity() but didn't work out :(

Comment: Thanks @quicklearner for having a look! I'm stuck on this for a long time now. I hope I get the solution soon.