# RecyclerView() Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create adapter for RecyclerView(), but it does not go to Overrided methods. Here is my code of Adapter

```
List<Division> divisions;
Context context;

public DivisionAdapter(List<Division> divisions, Context context) {
    this.divisions = divisions;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.division_item, parent, false);

    Logger.INSTANCE.debug("onCreaete" + divisions);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Logger.INSTANCE.debug("onBindViewHolder" + divisions);

    holder.address.setText(divisions.get(position).getAddress());
    holder.city.setText(divisions.get(position).getCityName());
    holder.title.setText(divisions.get(position).getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return divisions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    @BindView(R.id.item_address)
    TextView address;
    @BindView(R.id.item_title)
    TextView title;
    @BindView(R.id.item_city)
    TextView city;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(itemView);
    }
}
```

What is problem? I cannot understand, can someone help???
May be some little mistake?

Comment: "it does not go to Overrided methods", what do you mean?

Comment: My logs does not display in Logcat

Comment: try logging `divisions.size()` in `getItemCount()` method

Comment: and??? it returns me 1

Comment: recycler view is not visible?

Comment: no, it is visible

Comment: So you can view item in recycler view? but the log is not printing?

Comment: No I cannot see items in RecyclerView, and I gues that my viewHolder is not created, so items are not created. I did not set any parameters to recyclerView related to visibility

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119472/7557205)

Comment: no it does not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. I forgot to setLayoutManager to my RecyclerView. So be more attentive, and safe your time))