# RecyclerView is not displaying anything

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am doing recyclerview i have an activity and i want to display my fragment inside that activity which has a recyclerview.I dont know where i am going wrong pls help me with this

this is my activity
CategoryHairActivity.java

```
 import com.saloon.fragments.HairCategoryFragment;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class CategoryHairActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_hair);
        HairCategoryFragment hairCategoryFragment=new HairCategoryFragment();
        if(hairCategoryFragment!=null){
            FragmentManager fmanager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fmanager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.mainContent, hairCategoryFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category_hair, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

this is my fragment
HairCategoryFragment.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;

     import com.saloon.adapters.HairCategoryAdapter;
      import com.saloon.callbacks.HairCategoryInformation;
      import com.saloon.myapp.R;

       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
      import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
      import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
      import android.view.LayoutInflater;
      import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;

     public class HairCategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public HairCategoryAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.hair_service_list_view, container,    false);
    adapter=new HairCategoryAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.serviceListView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return rootView;
    }
    private List<HairCategoryInformation> getData() {
        List<HairCategoryInformation> data = new   ArrayList<HairCategoryInformation>();
        String[] serviceNames ={"razor cut","lime cut","onion cut","step cut"};
        String[] servicePrices={"200","300","400","500"};

            for(int i=0;i<serviceNames.length && i<servicePrices.length;i++){
                HairCategoryInformation current = new HairCategoryInformation();
                current.serviceName=serviceNames[i];
                current.servicePrice=servicePrices[i];
                data.add(current);
            }
            return data;
    }
    }
```

Viewholder.java

```
 import com.saloon.myapp.R;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HairCategoryViewHolder extends ViewHolder{

public CheckBox checkbox;
public TextView name,price;

public HairCategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
checkbox=(CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.serviceSelect);
name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.serviceName);
price=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.servicePrice);
}

}
```

HairCategoryInformation.java

```
  public class HairCategoryInformation {
    public String serviceName,servicePrice;
     }
```

HairCategoryAdapter.java

```
import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.List;

 import com.saloon.callbacks.HairCategoryInformation;
 import com.saloon.viewholder.HairCategoryViewHolder;

   import android.content.Context;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class HairCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HairCategoryViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<HairCategoryInformation> hairCategoryInformations = Collections.emptyList();
private Context context;
String text;
public HairCategoryAdapter(Context context,List<HairCategoryInformation> hairCategoryInformations) {
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.hairCategoryInformations=hairCategoryInformations;
}

@Override
public HairCategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(com.saloon.myapp.R.layout.hair_category_list, parent,false);
    HairCategoryViewHolder holder=new HairCategoryViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return hairCategoryInformations.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HairCategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
HairCategoryInformation current=hairCategoryInformations.get(position);
holder.name.setText(current.serviceName);
holder.price.setText(current.servicePrice);
holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(context, v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

Comment: use getter, setter and try it. may it work

Answer (score 0):

Why do you check hairCategoryFragment for null after initializing? Anyway, code seems to be fine, seems like you have issues in layout.

Comment: if i have recyclerview inside scrollview does that create an issue??

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't have RecyclerView inside ScrollView, you'd better to use the simple LinearLayout for your items in this case. But if you want to use RecyclerView check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515904/android-recyclerview-inside-a-scrollview