# RecyclerView inside RecyclerView is not scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager whose child items may have a vertical RecyclerView inside it. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have created adapters for this scenario. It shows it properly but internal Recyclerview is not scrolling no matter how many items are inside it. Can anyone suggest how to make internal and main RecyclerViews scroll?

Comment: Have you set `rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`?

Comment: yes I tried but it did not work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had to disable the touch event of the parent in case Recyclerview receives touch event. Here is the code snippet that worked for me:

```
RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener mScrollTouchListener = new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}; 

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(mScrollTouchListener);
```

I found the answer here: [Recyclerview inside Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36921079/851491)

Comment: This one is for the child view to apply. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Even if you scroll vertically after touching an item, it is still located in the scope of the horizontal scroll.

Comment: It will prevent parent to scroll after you have started scrolling child

Comment: this is great. But i need to pause my finger a bit in the childrecyclerview so i can scroll it. So i change MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE to MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, and it works better