# Android Vertical RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created an activity with a recycler view and a parent item, that also contains a vertical recycler view. When I am trying to add an item to a parent recycler view, everything is well, but I can scroll only the parent recycler view.

**My parent view initialization:**

```
parentRecyclerView.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
}
```

My child recycler view initialization is the same as parent, but with `LinearLayoutManager`.

Can anyone tell me how to enable scroll inside child recycler view?

Comment: try this **`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`** to your child recyclerview

Comment: I tried this, but scroll is still not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858634/recyclerview-inside-recyclerview-is-not-scrolling